# C++, overloaded operator + for Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, operators, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload operator +

```
template <typename U>
Mat <T> operator + ( const Mat <U> &A );
```

for the following matrix operations

```
Matrix (1,1) + scalar      = scalar
scalar + Matrix (1,1)      = scalar
Matrix(1,1) + Matrix(1,1)  = scalar
```

and a syntax (or alike)?

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T operator + ( const Mat <U> &M ) const;
```

Updated question:

The dimension as a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename U, const unsigned int TDim>
T operator + ( const Mat <U> &M, TDim <dim> ) const;
```

with the specialization for dim=1

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T operator + ( const Mat <U> &M, TDim <1> ) const;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless the dimensions of the matrix are made into template parameters of `Mat`, and you partially specialize the `Mat` template for `1x1` matrices.

Alternatively, you could return `Matrix(1,1)` and then have a conversion to scalar. If you did this, you'd have to accept the possibility of the conversion failing at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* overload `operator +` to do whatever you like.  The main question is, how are you defining the addition of a matrix and a scalar?  Even if you are adding a scalar to a 1x1 matrix, the operation is still undefined by conventional mathematics, because the 1x1 matrix is still a vector, rather than a scalar.

Comment: “the operation is still undefined” – is it? Mathematically, there’s no problem at all in treating a 1×1 matrix as a scalar. In fact, I believe that this is routinely done. For vectors at least there are no such qualms: 1-element vectors are the same as scalars from a mathematical point of view, and n-ary vectors are equivalent to n×1 matrices. In fact, this implies that a 1×1 matrix is a scalar.

Comment: @Konrad By mathematically, do you mean engineeringly?

Comment: @Yakk No I don’t. That’s what I learned in maths classes both at school and at University. And  although I recognise that this may depend on the actual definition, mathematicians are not above redefining core concepts and their operations to fit their particular purposes.

Comment: 1-element vectors are members of a vector space, and they aren't the same as the members of the field, even though there is a natural correspondence between said vectors and said field members. Ie, for Z_2^1, {} != {{{}}} (0 does not equal to the nullary function that maps to zero).  Usually you don't care, but a 1x1 matrix is not actually a scalar, it just corresponds very naturally to one. That natural correspondence is really useful -- and doing the conversion is usually a good idea. I mean, 2^Z = PowerSet(Z) is pretty standard, and it is an even worse abuse of this kind of correspondence!

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do this (and automatic conversions like this can be both dangerous and annoying), I would instead specialize `Matrix<1,1,T>` with an `operator T()` (or use `enable_if` type mojo so I wouldn't have to do boilerplate).

Then scalar addition would work by converting the `Matrix` to a `T` as a `T`, rather than an explicit override in `Matrix`.  In addition, your 1x1 `Matrix` gets to convert directly to a `T` implicitly, which you also seem to want.

As an aside, another really natural correspondence is from Scalars to the Scalar times an Identity Matrix of whatever size, and vice versa.  The 1x1 Matrix case is a special case of this, as all 1x1 Matrices are an Identity Matrix times a Scalar.

So the conversion (to an identity matrix times a scalar from a scalar) might make some sense and would require some overrides.  The opposite conversion is more dangerous because it is unreasonable to do the check at compile time, so it can fail.